# Shell script to find files with word1 & without word2

Tags: bash, shell, grep, find

I try to write a shell script that finds all files with word1 but without the word2

**Script**

```
echo -e "File name:"
read file
list=$(find "." -type f -name "$file")
co=$(cat $list | wc -l)
if [ $co -eq 0 ]
then
  echo "File not found"
else
  echo "File(s) List"
  echo "$list"
  result=$(grep -v "word2" $list| grep -rHn "word1" $list)
  if [ $? -ne 0 ]
  then
    echo "Word not found"
  else
    echo "File Line Word"
    echo "$result"
  fi
fi
```

***File1:***

```
word2@word1
```

***File2:***

```
test@word1
```

With this grep i get both files back but i want only `File2` without `word2`

Answer (score 1):

There are two mistakes in your "result=" line:

- the second grep should read on standard input (the output of the pipe) and not in $list
- it should not be recursive

So, I'd suggest:

```
result=$(grep -v "word2" $list| grep -Hn "word1" )
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script is based on filenames without spaces or newlines.
Your script is going wrong in `result=$(grep -v "word2" $list| grep -rHn "word1" $list)`. The second `grep` will not look at the results of the first `grep`, since is has the `$list` as an argument.
You wanted

```
  result=$(grep -rHn "word1" $(grep -lv "word2" $list))
```

This still fails, the second `grep` will return all files with at least one line not "word2".
First you need to find all files to be excluded, these are the files with "word2". These files need to be excluded from the ${list} (I use curly braces, get used to that).

```
   grep -vf <(grep -l "word2" ${list}) <(echo ${list} | tr " " "\n" )
```

Resulting in

```
result=$(grep -Hn "word1" 
  $(grep -vf <(grep -l "word2" ${list}) <(echo ${list} | tr " " "\n" )))
```

Another way would have been adding additional arguments to your `find` command (not finding word2 but finding word1)

```
find  "." -type f -name "${file}" ! -exec grep -q "word2" {} \; \
   -exec grep -Hn "word1" {} \; 2>/dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the most efficient `grep` method:

```
grep -lv word2 $(grep -l word1 File*)
```

Output:

```
File2
```

Note that the `-l` switch stops on the first match, which for large files can be a time saver.

To use `find` in that, while avoiding needless variables, do:

```
grep -lv word2 $(grep -l word1 $(find . -type f -name "$file") )
```